# Call Screen Flow from LWC in Partner Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community

I have some LWC buttons on a Partner Community and I want to call Screen Flow. My plan was to wrap the LWC in an Aura Component, send a customEvent from LWC, get the customEvent in the Aura Component and call the Screen Flow with Aura Controller. But it looks like my customEvent never get caught by Aura.

**partnerCommunityButtonLWC.html**

```
<template >
        <a class="slds-button slds-button_destructive" onclick={rejectLead}>Reject Lead</a>
</template>
```

**partnerCommunityButtonLWC.js**

```
rejectLead(){
    const event = new CustomEvent('reject', {
        detail: { message: 'lead rejected'}
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
    console.log('event sent');
}
```

**partnerCommunityButtonAura.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <c:partnerCommunityButtonLWC recordId="{!v.recordId}" onreject="{​​!c.handleRejectLead}​​"/>
    <lightning:flow aura:id="PCflow" />
</aura:component>
```

**partnerCommunityButtonAuraController.js**

```
({
handleRejectLead : function(component,event,helper){
    console.log('aura rejectLead');
    var flow = component.find("PCflow");
    flow.startFlow("Lead_rejection");
}
})
```

'event sent' from LWC display but 'aura rejectLead' Aura Controller never display...

What am I missing?

Is there some Community limitation that can prevent my customEvent to work?

Comment: The only thing I can see is... sometimes the object you are passing to the custom event seems to cause problems. Try making the detail object first  - eg: `const eventDetail = {"message":"lead rejected"};
const event = new CustomEvent('reject', {detail: eventDetail });`

Comment: thanks @CasparHarmer, I tried but it doesn't change anything...